# Dependent Bernoulli trials

Tags: machine-learning, discrete-data, mixture-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

The probability of a sequence of n independent Bernoulli trials can be easily expressed as
$$p(x_1,...,x_n|p_1,...,p_n)=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{x_i}(1-p_i)^{1-x_i}$$
but what if the trials are not independent?

How would one express the probability to capture the dependence?

Comment: did you look at de Finetti theorem and exchangeable sequences ? http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~steffen/teaching/grad/definetti.pdf

Comment: What is the dependence? E.g. Summing over the N trials must equal K? There must be an even number of 'true' results, etc. Once you define the kind of dependence it will be possible to write down the actual likelihood more concretely.

Answer (score 8):

There are expressions you can write down, but I hope you realize how uninformative they are. Saying that the variables are not known to be indpendent, without saying anything else, gives no usable information. It's like saying that you have a friend whose name is not known to be  Bob, then asking what you can say about your friend's height and age. So, here is a nearly meaningless restatement:

$$p(x_1,...,x_n) = \prod_i p(X_i=x_i|X_1=x_1,...,X_{i-1}=x_{i-1}).$$

Comment: Could you please help me about a similar one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2830527/390226 ?