# Dependent Bernoulli trials

Tags: machine-learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dependent Bernoulli trials](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46597/dependent-bernoulli-trials)

The probability of a sequence of n independent Bernoulli trials can be easily expressed as

```
p(x_1,...,x_n|p_1,...,p_n)=prod_{i=1 to n}p_i^{x_i}(1-p_i)^{1-x_i}
```

but what if the trials are not independent? how would one express the probability to capture the dependence?

Comment: It's a discrete math question...

Comment: Since this isn't about "a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, [or] software tools commonly used by programmers", or a "practical, answerable problem[] that [is] unique to the programming profession" [(FAQ)](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), it's off-topic on SO.

Comment: OK, sorry then.